# Why does BROADCAST need to be specified in ifcfg file

Tags: centos, networking, rhel, oracle-linux

When configuring networking in RHEL 7, Cent OS 7, Oracle 7, etc...

The documentation suggests specifying `IPADDR`, `NETMASK`, and `BROADCAST` in the `ifcfg-xxx` file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

1. Why does the user need to specify `BROADCAST` when it can be calculated from the `IPADDR` and `NETMASK` like the pseudocode below?

   ```
   NETWORK=IPADDR & NETMASK
   BROADCAST=(0xFFFFFFFF ^ NETMASK) | NETWORK
   ```
2. Is there a case where you would want a BROADCAST address to be set to something other than what I would calculate in part 1?

Comment: Sometimes, things are just a legacy from the past. The use of .0 addresses to denote networks, and .255 addresses to denote broadcasts is merely convention. Not actually driven a limitation or requirement of the technology.

If you really want to dig into it, the convention was somewhat formalized by RFC922. (see: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc922) And it was initially proposed in 1981/1982 by https://www.rfc-editor.org/ien/ien212.txt from BBN.

Comment: A broadcast address doesn't always end in .255 as in the case of 10.0.0.1/28 which would have a broadcast address of 10.0.0.15.

Comment: `ip addr show` lists a valid broadcast address even when it is not specified in the ifcfg file.